# How to implement OAuth2 in Jersey?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jersey, jax-rs

I developed a JAX-RS project. I used Jersey for it. I'm trying to figure out what's the best solution for authentication, since my API will be consumed through a web and a mobile application.

OAuth2 seams to be the best solution for the case.

Does anyone know a good and easy to follow example on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [srb4j](https://github.com/chenjianjx/srb4j), a simple RESTFul backend for Java, with out-of-box, oauth2-based authentication.

Its tech stack is: Jersey2 + Spring + MyBatis + MySQL.  Since it's an open source project, you can replace MyBatis/MySQL with the persistence frameworks and DBs you like.

It's "easy" enough, since you can set up the project in a few minutes.